# EF Core - Not loading all child entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string? CategoryName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategory { get; set; }
}

public partial class BookCategory
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public partial class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
}
```

I wish to return an array of Category's, with a child array of BookCategory which has a one to one with a Book.

Using a call like this;

```
public async Task<List<Category>> test()
{
    var query = dbContext.Category
                .Include(p => p.BookCategory) 
                .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Book)
                .OrderBy(p => p.CategoryID) as IQueryable<Category>;

    var data = await query.ToListAsync();

    return data;
}
```

I have dummy data like so:

```
insert into kiosk.Category (CategoryID, CategoryName) values (1, 'Horror')
insert into kiosk.Category (CategoryID, CategoryName) values (2, 'Fantasy')

insert into kiosk.Book (BookID, Title) values (1, 'Space shooty')
insert into kiosk.Book (BookID, Title) values (2, 'Elf shooty')

insert into kiosk.BookCategory (BookID, CategoryID) values (1, 2)
insert into kiosk.BookCategory (BookID, CategoryID) values (2, 2)
```

However the response I receive for this request only gives me one record for category 2 rather the expected two.

```
[
    {
        "categoryID": 1,
        "categoryName": "Horror",
        "bookCategory": []
    },
    {
        "categoryID": 2,
        "categoryName": "Fantasy",
        "bookCategory": [
            {
                "categoryID": 2,
                "bookID": 1,
                "book": {
                    "bookID": 1,
                    "title": "Space shooty"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

DBContext:

```
    public class BooksDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Book> book { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<BookCategory> BookCategory { get; set; } 

        public BooksDbContext()
        { }

        public BooksDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        { }

        public BooksDbContext(string connectionString)
        {
            this.connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BookCategoryConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CategoryTestConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new BookConfiguration());

        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString))
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
        }
    }
```

The Three Configurations are as follow

```
    public class BookCategoryConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BookCategory>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BookCategory> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("BookCategory");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.BookID);
            builder.HasKey(x => x.CategoryID);         

            builder.HasOne(a => a.Category).WithMany(b => b.BookCategory).HasForeignKey(c => c.CategoryID); // FK_POSCategoryProduct_POSCategory
        }
    }


    public class CategoryTestConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Category> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Category");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.CategoryID);

            builder.Property(x => x.CategoryID).HasColumnName(@"CategoryID").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.CategoryName).HasColumnName(@"CategoryName").HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(50);          

        }
    }


    public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Book");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.BookID);

            builder.Property(x => x.BookID).HasColumnName(@"BookID").HasColumnType("int").IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.Title).HasColumnName(@"Title").HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(50);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you shure that there are 2 values in Database? Can you attach screenshot? Sometimes we forget to press "Commit" button when changing data by UI tools.  One more point: You should ignore propperty Category for class BookCategory. Due to there is I cyclic refference.

Comment: Could you try to select from database List if BookCategory objects. Is there are more than one?

Comment: @TemaTre They have provided the scripts to create data & schema, I think the issue should reproduce with just those - also no need to select, they have provided inserts. Also why do they need to ignore the property?

Comment: The database has the data shown in the scripts supplied.

Comment: There is a cyclic refference. Category -> BookCategory and BookCategory -> Category. This may be a problem.

Comment: Please provide information about init of scheme. Is it CodeFirst or is it DatabaseFirst?

Comment: @RebeccaJ, your explanation makes my answer irrelevant, I deleted that. Since you already have schema, have you tried scaffolding the context? Does it produce same class hierarchy?

Comment: Add your DBContext code for those objects. How you have DBContext setup can dramatically change how EF behaves.

Comment: @JonathanAllen The question has been updated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The model represents a standard many-to-many relationship via explicit join entity.

The problem is the fluent mapping of the join entity key:

```
builder.HasKey(x => x.BookID);
builder.HasKey(x => x.CategoryID);
```

The `HasKey` method (as most if not all of the fluent APIs) is *not* additive. The later call wins (replaces the previous).

The effect of the above code is that EF Core considers the `CategoryID` to be an *unique* key of `BookCategory` table, hence loads only 1 record per `CategoryID`.

Of course the idea was to define a standard composite primary key of the join entity. This is achieved (similar to all fluent APIs allowing multiple properties) by using anonymous type (shown in composite key section example of the EF Core [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) documentation topic).

Applying it to your scenario would be replacing the above 2 lines with

```
builder.HasKey(x => new { x.BookID, x.CategoryID });
```